# Valve driver specifications

Tags: datasheet, driver, solenoid-valve

I need to control a NSF/ODE JM R1 2/2 valve. [Here](https://gofile.io/d/2FCSNQ) the datasheet (Gofile link).
I cannot understand the electrical requirements. It says:

- Power: 5W DC
- Running power: 10 VA AC
- Startup power: 15 VA AC

But I don't find anything about the minimum/maximum/nominal voltages. And I don't understand why there are specifications for AC and DC, and for DC there is no difference about running/startup power.

Comment: Try finding a data sheet in English.

Comment: @Andyaka, the product is made in Italy and I'm not aware of an English datasheet. Every time I find an English datasheet I try to read it, without asking for an Italian one :-)

Comment: I mean, if you need help to translate any section you're welcome. But I guess if there is any voltage/current specification it should be clear (at least due to measurement units)

Comment: Just think about what you are saying. How would I know what sections I might want translating if I can't read them?

Comment: Call the vendor. Maybe the solenoids come separately and probably made for different voltages, DC, AC,...

Comment: Datasheet specifies "Bobbin type L" on page 3. Which in the full databook is presumably spec'ed elsewhere. It will be possible to order it wound for any variety of voltages and currents, providing 5W (DC. More required for AC to ride through the zero crossings). Vendor or their distributor will tell you which ones are standard/stock items even if the full catalogue doesn't.

Comment: http://www.odevalve.com/pdfs/JM-series%20HYDR.pdf ???